# How Authentication with NSURLCredential in Alamofire works?

Tags: authentication

I am new to IOS development. I am just making a simple login page. Now how can i check that the username and password i entered is right or not. I have an API and I have done registration using Alamofire. I am not sure but i think we can do this using Authentication with NSURLCredential in Alamofire. Please help me in understanding how this method works or any other solution.

Thanks in advance !!